# Rejection of ADF-test for log returns and AIC selected ARIMA(0,0,0) and ARIMA (0,0,0) with a drift?

Tags: arima, stationarity, aic, augmented-dickey-fuller, random-walk

I use monthly log returns for some stock portfolios and rejects the null of the ADF-test for both. Hereafter I use AIC to select best fitting models using auto.arima in R. The selected models are ARIMA(0,0,0) with zero-mean and ARIMA (0,0,0) with a drift. Now I have a couple of questions.

1. Since I use log returns, equal to having differenced the log prices. Would it then be more appropriate to denote the number of differencings d as 1, so the models are ARIMA(0,1,0)? I have read others using similar approach who denotes d as 0, therefore I'm in doubt. Besides this the general nature of calculating returns for financial data seems more appropriate as original data.
2. Since I reject the null of the ADF-test there is evidence for the series being stationary, and therefore not a Random Walk. Though the models selected by AIC is equivalent to either white noise or random walk with a drift?

Comment: None of the selected model is random walk with drift and none has a drift term either.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @RichardHardy. Can you elaborate on how come the model don’t have a drift, since the selected model by AIC was a ARIMA(0,0,0) with a significant positive intercept? I would expect that was the drift of the series? 

Besides this how come you don’t regard them as random walk? Due to the data is log returns, would it then be appropriate to present them as ARIMA(0,1,0 and ARIMA(0,1,0) with a drift equivalent to random walks?

Comment: I meant that ARIMA(0,0,0) is white noise while ARIMA(0,0,0) with a nonzero intercept is still white noise. If you have in mind ARIMA(0,1,0) with zero intercept instead of ARIMA(0,0,0), then it is a random walk. With intercept, that becomes random walk with drift.